# Get method's parameters names and values from inside method

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way in .NET to know what parameters and their values were passed to a method. Reflection way? This will be used from inside the method. It has to be generic so it can be used from any method. This is for logging purposes.

Comment: I ended up making this [User Activity Logging, Telemetry and Variables in Global Exception Handlers project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326673/user-activity-logging-telemetry-and-variables-in-global-exception-handlers)

Answer (score 11):

Call `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters()`.
However, it is not possible to get the parameter values; due to JIT optimization, they might not even exist anymore.

Answer (score 7):

[`MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx) will give you information about the current method and then get information about the parameters using [`GetParameters()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx).

Comment: this does not give parameter values

Answer (score 6):

What you're trying to do can be achieved easily using aspect oriented programming. There are good tutorials online, I'll point to two of them:

- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Logging--the-AOP-way.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UsingAOPInCSharp.aspx

Comment: +1 AFAIK this is the only efficient way to achieve this goal.  The only other way would be to use another process to debug the current process, nasty, unreliable, and slow.

Comment: Why the downvote? AOP/weaving could be one solution for the problem.

Comment: aspect oriented programming is a methodology. It still translates eventually to some .NET api's.

Answer (score 5):

```
public void FunctionWithParameters(string message, string operationName = null, string subscriptionId = null)
{
    var parameters = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
    this.PrintParams(parameters, message, operationName, subscriptionId);

}

public void PrintParams(ParameterInfo[] paramNames, params object[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{paramNames[i].Name} : {args[i]}");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: not bad but you need to remember to pass in all the parameter's values or the log will end up being innacurate.

Answer (score 0):

You need AOP to achieve what you are looking for. 
in c# you can use DispatchProxy to do that.
Check the following [How to wrap existing object instance into DispatchProxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922735/how-to-wrap-existing-object-instance-into-dispatchproxy/58309352#58309352)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays a feature that could be used to achieve this is [Roslyn's Source Generators](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/source-generators.md).

In this way, the code that gets the parameters' values would be generated at compile-time based on the method definition. Could be interpreted as “*compile-time reflection*”.

Let's show an example to try to explain it better:

```cs
public void MethodInspectingItsOwnParameters(
    [Description("First parameter")] 
    string paramName_1,
    [Description("Second parameter")] 
    int paramName_2,
    // ...
    [Description("N-th parameter")] 
    object paramName_N,
    // ...
    [Description("Last parameter")] 
    bool paramName_M)
{
    var paramsAndValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

    //  -
    //  => Put here the code that, using Roslyn's compile time 
    //     metaprogramming, inspect the parameters from the method 
    //     definition and at compile time generate the code that 
    //     at run time will get the parameters's values and load 
    //     them into [paramsAndValues]
    //  -

    // #Rosalyn generated code 
    //  · Code autogenerated at compile time 
    //    => loads parameter's values into [paramsAndValues]
    // -
    //  Eg (Hypothetical example of the code generated at compile 
    //     time by Roslyn's metaprogramming):
    //
    //      paramsAndValues.Add("paramName_0", paramName_1);
    //      ...
    //      paramsAndValues.Add("paramName_N", paramName_N);
    //      ...
    //      paramsAndValues.Add("paramName_M", paramName_M);
    //
    // - Note: this code will be regenerated with each compilation, 
    //         so there no make sense to do nameof(paramName_N) 
    //         to obtaint parameter's name
    // #End Rosalyn generated code

    foreach (var param in paramsAndValues)
    {
        string paramName = param.Key;
        object paramValue = param.Value;

        // In this section of the normal code (not generated at 
        // compile time) do what you require with the 
        // parameters/values already loaded into [paramsAndValues]
        // by the compile time generated code
    }
}
```

Comment: At this point, I have never *played* with Roslyn's Source Generators. This question would be a nice learning exercise to do. If I take the time, I'll come back here to add some (hopefully) working code to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here goes my solution for logging all the parameters and their values. **ONLY wihtin a Controller Context**:

```
    public static string CallParams = "";
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);                    
         CallParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filterContext.ActionParameters);
    }
```

Hope it helps