# How to wrap existing object instance into DispatchProxy?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, realproxy

I'm looking for `RealProxy` replacement in .NET Core, and this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4091) forwards me to [`DispatchProxy`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy).

It has simple API, but it's unclear, how to wrap *existing* object into proxy.
E.g., having this interface:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string Bar(int boo);
}
```

and this implementation:

```
class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    public string Bar(int boo)
    {
        return $"Value {boo} was passed";
    }
}
```

how to get what I want?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fooInstance = new FooImpl();
        var proxy = DispatchProxy.Create<IFoo, FooProxy>();

        var s = proxy.Bar(123);

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

class FooProxy : DispatchProxy
{
    protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
    {
        return targetMethod.Invoke(/* I need fooInstance here */, args);
    }
}
```

Since `DispatchProxy` descendants must have parameterless constructor, the only idea I have is to invent some method, like this:

```
class FooProxy : DispatchProxy
{
    private object target;

    public void SetTarget(object target)
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
    {
        return targetMethod.Invoke(target, args);
    }
}
```

and use it this way:

```
var fooInstance = new FooImpl();
var proxy = DispatchProxy.Create<IFoo, FooProxy>();

((FooProxy)proxy).SetTarget(fooInstance);

// the rest of code...
```

Is this correct approach?

Comment: The cast to FooProxy above won't compile because the type of proxy is IFoo. Declaring proxy to be of type object will solve the problem

Comment: @robertfriberg: It *will* compile. This was pasted directly from sample, which compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: Doesn't compile for me, see https://twitter.com/robertfriberg/status/903527168403275784

Comment: `DispatchProxy.Create<IFoo, FooProxy>()` return an `IFoo`, the compiler won't allow a cast too FooProxy. I'm using VS2017, C# 7.0, and .Net Standard 1.6

Comment: @robertfriberg: ah, I see. Our samples are not identical. The reason is that your code uses generics. While cast above is allowed for non-generic code, generic one requires double cast (my production code is generic one and contains double cast too). But in the context of a question, code from above is OK.

Comment: I have an answer that I've supplied to a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54607410/2648798 - it might help to see a working implementation of DispatchProxy?

Comment: Surprisingly DispatchProxy is not nicely usable out of the box. Creating a generic Utility class is a suggested solution: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-realproxy-usage-to-dispatchproxy/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that there is no other option here than to cast the generated `IFoo` to the known proxy type (`FooProxy`) and use a custom method or property on `FooProxy`. There is no public API to add constructor arguments or return the proxy as the implementation type. However, `DispatchProxy.Create()` will return an instance of a subclass of `FooProxy` whose type is generated at runtime via reflection and IL emitting.

If you are looking at other ways to quickly wrap an implementation and replace interface methods / virtual methods, I suggest using mocking frameworks instead (FakeItEasy, Moq, NSubstitute etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using proxies for some sort of extended logging. There's no goal to replace implementation. I just need to have ability to turn on/off parameters and return values logging for particular instance, and call original implementation.

Comment: So the cleanest way would probably be to add sth like a `Logger` and `TargetInstance` property on your custom dispatch class if you want to use `DispatchProxy`.

Comment: fyi the source code is here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy/src/System/Reflection

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own Generic class that inherit from DispatchProxy and has own static Create that has an extra parameter from type target.

example

```
public class AopAction<T>:DispatchProxy
{
  #region Private Fields
  private Action<MethodInfo,object[],object> ActAfter;
  private Action<MethodInfo,object[]> ActBefore;
  private Action<MethodInfo,object[],Exception> ActException;
  private T Decorated;
  #endregion Private Fields

  #region Public Methods
  public static T Create(T decorated,Action<MethodInfo,object[]> actBefore = null,Action<MethodInfo,object[],object> actAfter = null,Action<MethodInfo,object[],Exception> actException = null)
  {
    object proxy = Create<T,AopAction<T>>();
    SetParameters();
    return (T)proxy;
    void SetParameters()
    {
      var me = ((AopAction<T>)proxy);
      me.Decorated = decorated == null ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decorated)) : decorated;
      me.ActBefore = actBefore;
      me.ActAfter = actAfter;
      me.ActException = actException;
    }
  }
  #endregion Public Methods

  #region Protected Methods
  protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod,object[] args)
  {
    _ = targetMethod ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(targetMethod));

    try
    {
      ActBefore?.Invoke(targetMethod,args);
      var result = targetMethod.Invoke(Decorated,args);
      ActAfter?.Invoke(targetMethod,args,result);
      return result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      ActException?.Invoke(targetMethod,args,ex);
      throw ex.InnerException;
    }
  }
  #endregion Protected Methods
}
```

to use your example

```
var proxy=AopAction<IFoo>.Create(new FooImpl());
```